# Dojo event is not working due to parser

Tags: javascript, dojo

my code snippet

```
<div id="mainMenu" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBar">
            <div id="edit" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBarItem">Add Hero</div>
            <div id="view" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBarItem">Grid View</div>
            <div id="task" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBarItem">Detailed View</div>
        </div>
    <script >
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: 1,
            parseOnLoad: 0
        };      
    </script>
    <script>
    require([
                   "dojo/dom",
                    "dojo",
                    "dojo/parser",
                    "dojo/query",
                    "dojo/on",
                    "dijit/Menu",
                    "dojo/domReady!"
                ], function(dom,dojo ,parser, query,on){

                    //var result = query("#edit");
                    var myButton=dojo.byId("edit");console.log(myButton);
                    on(myButton, "click", function(){
                        alert("Cliked on menu item");
                    });

                });
    </script>
```

My goal is to display the menu name on click. But the problem with this is that the parser events will not be triggered. If I change `parseOnLoad` to `0` or `flase`, then I will get the alert message but menu getting disturbed and if I set the `parseOnLoad` to `1` then click event is not work?

Comment: Can you also post your HTML code for the edit button? Right now I think you're using DOM events, while you're actually trying to use widget events.

Comment: Here my HTML Code

<div id="mainMenu" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBar">
            <div id="edit" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBarItem">Add Hero</div>
            <div id="view" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBarItem">Grid View</div>
            <div id="task" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBarItem">Detailed View</div>
        </div>

Answer (score 1):

While your code might be working for DOM nodes, it doesn't work for widgets (dijits). This is also the reason why it works when you disable the `parseOnLoad` feature, because you never parsed the DOM nodes to widgets. This means your DOM events will work, but of course, the menu is never created as a widget, so you have problems with your menu.

Now, to solve this problem, you need to use the `dijit/registry` to retrieve the menu item:

```js
var myButton = registry.byId("edit");
```

The `dojo/on` module is only for DOM events, so you will have to replace that as well. Luckily for us, the widget object (that's what you retrieve by using the registry), already has an `on()` function (see [API docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/MenuBarItem#1_9dijit_MenuBarItem_on)), which we can use like this:

```js
myButton.on("click", function() {
    alert("Cliked on menu item");
});
```

The last thing we need to change is the initial DOM loaded event (`dojo/domReady!`). Widgets are parsed **after** the DOM is loaded. Which means that if we listen to a DOM-ready event, we will not be able to retrieve the widgets. The event handler for checking whether the DOM is loaded **and** the widgets are parsed, is by using the `dojo/ready` module. It has a slightly different syntax than the `dojo/domReady!` plugin, because we use it like this:

```js
ready(function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Or in your case:

```js
ready(function() {
    var myButton = registry.byId("edit");
    console.log(myButton);

    myButton.on("click", function() {
        alert("Clicked on menu item"); 
    });
});
```

The complete example can also be found at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/jGc79/).